# No tetwork (sim card doesn't allow connection to this )

Tags: huawei, connection-issues, sim-card, gsm

Help please.
I repaired my phone's imei with xposed and now i have no network connection.
When i choose a network it says: sim card doesn't allow connection to this.
I put the sim in other phones and sim was ok.
tried only gsm , only wcdma and no change.
Phone model is y560 L02 qualcomm

Comment: Xposed only works on Java based apps, not on native apps and not on Android that are not an app. Hence it only "repairs" what is displayed to you, however the RIL, the daemon that performs the actual interaction with the mobile network is not affected by Xposed.